# angular Routing: when I call controller the second will be executed

Tags: angularjs

Im uning angular to make page login, I use template login.html and controller login.html, the problem is when I call login controller the main controller will be executed automatically !

and I found : warning: tried to load angular more than once.

this is my JS:

```js
trainingApp.config(['$routeProvider' ,function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login',{
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller:  'loginCtrl'
    })
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
            redirectTo : "/"
        });
}]);



trainingApp.controller('loginCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.alertt = function(){
   // console.log("ok");
    alert("okkkkkkk");
}
}]);




trainingApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','$timeout', 'apiService','$location', function ($scope,$timeout, apiService,$location) {
    console.log('hello');
    }]);
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Plannification Des Formations</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle/bootstrap-tokenfield.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle/jquery-ui.css">
            <script src="public/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> 
            <script src="public/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script src="public/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
            <script src="node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
            <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
            <script src="bower_components/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
            <script src="public/daypilot/daypilot-all.min.js"></script>
            <script src="public/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
            <script src="public/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <!-- <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script> -->
                  <script src="controllers/app.js"></script>
                     <script src="controllers/mainCrtl.js"></script>
                        <script src="services/apiService.js"></script>
                      
</head>
<body  data-ng-app="training" data-ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-view>
.......
</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```html
<button id="btn-login"  class="btn btn-success "  ng-href="#!/">Login  </button>
```

Comment: post your `index and  login.html`

Comment: I posted .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove `ng-controller="mainCtrl"` from your `html`, as you have already defined controller in `$routeProvider` config.

Comment: thanks it work,     but what about WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.  when I click on button I found that in console !!

Comment: change also , `ng-view` to be like `<div ng-view></div>` or `<ng-view></ng-view>`

Comment: doesn't work like that !! what about the warning please ?

Comment: @Fredj It's because of your href (ng-href="#!/") in your button, I dont think there is a route for that. Hence it's recursive and trying to load it again and again

Comment: @Fredj : your `href` need to point right path. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/okdexrLc/) to redirection.

Comment: also if you facing issue with `!` symbol. add `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('' )` inside your route config, `.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');`

Comment: I think that's because when I click on the button to get back to index it reload the angular library no ??

Comment: just use `ng-href="#/Login"`

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code like this.

```
.when('/',{
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    controller: 'mainCtrl',
    abstract: true,
})
```